MaxListenersExceededWarning:Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected.11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]
this is the error that i encounter whenever i try to install packages. how do i fix it? i am not an advanced developer so kindly be as descriptive as possible

(node:6461) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.

i was trying to create a new next app with the command npx create-next-app@latest. but got this error instead. now i am unable to install any new packages and libraries
